# Adding lists in a specific format

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I have a list like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

And second list like this:

```
b = [4,5,6]
```

I want these lists to be added like this:

```
[1,2,3, some_atom:[4,5,6]]
```

So i want an `atom` to in the list like this.

I am trying this:

```
 a ++ [some_atom: b]
```

Its giving me the output:

```
[1, 2, 3 {:some_atom, [4, 5, 6]}]
```

Can any one suggest how can I do that if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing and work the same way. It is how [Keyword](http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists) lists work.

Try it in `iex`:

```elixir
iex(1)> [foo: "bar"]
[foo: "bar"]

iex(2)> [{:foo, "bar"}]
[foo: "bar"]
```

Cool right?, Check it.

```elixir
iex> [foo: "bar", baz: "bar"] == [{:foo, "bar"}, {:baz, "bar"}]
true
```

And your example:

```elixir
iex> [1, 2, 3, some_atom: [4, 5, 6]] == [1, 2, 3, {:some_atom, [4, 5, 6]}]
true
```

[image: iex]

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is the proper result. In Elixir, a [Keyword](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html) list is just a list of tuples. So,

```
[key: :value, other_key: :other_value]
```

is the same as

```
[{:key, :value}, {:other_key, :other_value}]
```

In fact, the first is just syntactic sugar for the second.

Comment: `key: :value, other_key: :other_value` alone is an invalid syntax; please correct the answer to use proper keyword there `[key: :value, other_key: :other_value]` (and possible explaining where brackets can be omitted, namely, when passing arguments to functions expecting a keyword there.)

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It was just a miss type on my part.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you notice that `[1,2,3, some_atom: [4,5,6]]` is equivalent to `[1,2,3, {:some_atom, [4,5,6]}]`, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself. And your original approach is correct. You can prove it by

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = a ++ [some_atom: b]

[1,2,3, some_atom:[4,5,6]] = c  # pattern matching passes
```